# Umgangsformen: Du oder Sie?

Tags: discussion, faq

Als Referenz: Sollten sich die Benutzer dieser Seite eher duzen oder siezen?

> Only applicable for communication in German, but: should the users of this site use *Du* or *Sie* when addressing each other?

Answer (score 28):

Die Benutzer sollten sich duzen, aber Abweichler werden einfach als Antwort geduzt.

Comment: „Du“ hat sich im deutschen Online-Sprachraum einfach durchgesetzt, Siezen klingt manchmal geradezu unhöflich (siehe [Netiquette](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netiquette)). Lediglich Blogs von Zeitungen weichen noch ab, weil man dort wohl noch nichts vom Internet gehört hat.

Comment: Aus Höflichkeit empfehle ich sehr, jeden der siezt ebenfalls zu siezen aber sofort das Du anzubieten.

Answer (score 6):

Jeder kann tun, was er will, aber die Antwort sollte dieselbe Form verwenden.

Answer (score 4):

Jeder kann tun, was er will, es gibt keine Richtlinien.

Answer (score 3):

Die Benutzer sollten sich siezen, aber Abweichler werden einfach als Antwort gesiezt.

Answer (score -3):

Die Benutzer sollten sich siezen und das sollte durch edits durchgesetzt werden.

Comment: warum sich selbst Arbeit schaffen?

Answer (score -4):

Die Benutzer sollten sich duzen und das sollte durch edits durchgesetzt werden.