# Suggestions for the editable section of the help center

Tags: discussion, help-center

The [Help Center](https://german.stackexchange.com/help) for German Language Stack Exchange includes a section that can be edited by moderators:

[image: Help Center]

This means that the community can decide to write a suitable text and then the moderators can edit it into that space. Up to now, this section is empty. Therefore, I am asking for suggestions on how this section should be used.

By way of comparison, the [help center of Buddhism Stack Exchange](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) includes a section with “useful resources”.

Answer (score 1):

If nobody else has a suggestion, I suggest to link selected meta-questions tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), grouped into some categories:

> In addition to the general help on using Stack Exchange provided below, please consider the following articles specific to this site:
>
> #### Contributing / Mitwirken
>
> - [What language should the questions be written in?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1)
> - [How do I format the words in German (or another language) we are talking about?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/554)
> - [Umgangsformen: Du oder Sie?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36)
> - [Editing orthographic errors](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4)
>
> #### Which questions are a good fit this site? / Welche Fragen können hier gestellt werden?
>
> - [What topics can I ask about here?](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
> - [How do I ask good, on-topic questions for translations or about differences?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/628)
> - [Are questions related to peer review of a text on topic?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/919)
> - [Does my translation request belong here and if not, where and how shall I ask it?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1057)
> - [If the same question is asked in German and English is it a duplicate?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14)
> - [Wann soll ich welchen Schließgrund bei Fragen nach Übersetzungen, Bedeutungen u. Ä. verwenden?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1103)
> - [Should we leave a comment when closing a question?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/492)

I left out some questions that I do not expect people to look for in the help centre or that mostly reflect existing help-centre articles.

Note that I also added `help/on-topic`, the only custom site from the help centre.